# java,ArrayList,code morse

Tags: java, arraylist

у меня задание написать программу в java, что-бы из простого алфавита переводил в азбуку морзе, нельзя использовать hashmap, hashset, выдает ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 65, Size: 0
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:685)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:494)
    at com.company.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:25)

package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main{

    final static String[][] code = {
            {"A", ".-     "}, {"B", "-...   "}, {"C", "-.-.   "}, {"D", "-..    "},
            {"E", ".      "}, {"F", "..-.   "}, {"G", "--.    "}, {"H", "....   "},
            {"I", "..     "}, {"J", ".---   "}, {"K", "-.-    "}, {"L", ".-..   "},
            {"M", "--     "}, {"N", "-.     "}, {"O", "---    "}, {"P", ".--.   "},
            {"Q", "--.-   "}, {"R", ".-.    "}, {"S", "...    "}, {"T", "-      "},
            {"U", "..-    "}, {"V", "...-   "}, {"W", ".-   - "}, {"X", "-..-   "},
            {"Y", "-.--   "}, {"Z", "--..   "}, {"0", "-----  "}, {"1", ".----  "},
            {"2", "..---  "}, {"3", "...--  "}, {"4", "....-  "}, {"5", ".....  "},
            {"6", "-....  "}, {"7", "--...  "}, {"8", "---..  "}, {"9", "----.  "},
            {"'", ".----. "}, {":", "---... "}, {",", "--..-- "}, {"-", "-....- "},
            {"(", "-.--.- "}, {".", ".-.-.- "}, {"?", "..--.. "}, {";", "-.-.-. "},
            {"/", "-..-.  "}, {"-", "..--.- "}, {")", "---..  "}, {"=", "-...-  "},
            {"@", ".--.-. "}, {"\"", ".-..-."}, {"+", ".-.-.  "}, {" ", "/"}};
    final static List<String> ascii = new ArrayList<String>();
static {
    for (String[] pair : code){
        ascii.add(pair[0].charAt(0), pair[1].trim());
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
        printMorse("   Hello     World!");
    }
    static void printMorse(String input) {
        System.out.printf("%s %n", input);

        input = input.trim().replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").toUpperCase();
        for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            String s = ascii.get(c);
            if (s != null){
                System.out.printf("%s ", s);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
ascii.add(pair[0].charAt(0), pair[1].trim());
```

Дело в том что `pair[0].charAt(0)` это `char`, что в Java одно и то же что и `int`. Когда ты пытаешься заполнить `ascii`, в частности при добавлении буквы `A`, ты пытаешься вставить 65-ый элемент списка. А список на этот момент состоит из 0 элементов. Собственно, ошибка об этом и говорит.

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 65, Size: 0`

Т.е. список пустой, а ты сразу пихаешь в него 65-ый элемент

Тебе нужен другой подход к формированию списка `ascii`

например, список `ascii` может быть типа `List<Pair<String, String>>`

правда, такого класса в `Java` нет, но его легко написать

```
public class Pair<F, S> {
    public final F first;
    public final S second;

    /**
     * Constructor for a Pair.
     *
     * @param first the first object in the Pair
     * @param second the second object in the pair
     */
    public Pair(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Хотя вообще способов много